# Question about ambiguty in meaning of "corruption" and " have been shaken" in the context

Tags: word-meaning

Cengiz Aktar agrees that Turkey has changed since the military became directly involved in politics. But he says the country remains at risk for corruption.

"The police and justice have been shaken and destabilized. Therefore we don’t know who will ensure the public order, with that many criminals there in the streets of the country.”

........... ..... http://m.learningenglish.voanews.com/a/turkey-prisoners-india-elections/1879212.html

...............

I have my doubts if the word "corruption" here has to do with "a change" (according to longman second meaning ) or it is about dishonest behaviour.   And also " have been shaken" . Does it mean become shocked?

Second meaning of corruption. 
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/corruption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, corruption has never been defined as a simple 'change'. It is almost always used when describing a change with bad consequences. The corruption of the government in this case is saying there is a risk that some force that would not benefit the country could control the government in future.

'To be shaken' is quite similar to being 'shocked', as it tends to describe someone who is facing something they weren't prepared for, that caught them by surprise. It can also mean that they are becoming scared of the situation and are feeling tense in this context.

Ending note: that second definition of corruption is 'correct' but *very* rarely used. The word commonly has negative connotations applied to it.

Comment: The 2nd definition is used _almost_ exclusively in the context of words and expressions as in "Thursday is a corruption of Thor's Day." So I think saying that it's "very rarely used" is not fair.